# what is the probability of the below hand?

Tags: probability

The hand contains three cards of one rank and the remaining two cards have two other ranks.I have tried doing this way:

```
total no of possible hands=52C5
favourable hands= 13c1*4c3*12c1*11c1*4c1*4c1
prob=favourable hands/possible hands
```

but I'm getting wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're (typically) double counting hands. When you do $C(12,1)\cdot C(11,1)$, you're taking order into account. For example, doing this, you could select a $5$ first and then a $6$ or a $6$ first and then a $5$. What you want is $C(12,2)$.